# Hibernate selectBeforeUpdate property @org.hibernate.Entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

When we set selectBeforeUpdate=true, before making update, Hibernate runs Select query checks if current objects is same as that there in DB and then decide wether to fire Update query or not.

My Question is that how hibernate decide if both the objects are same or not. Is it by calling equals() or comparing each field of the object, no mater what is the implementation of equals()?

Comment: Try creating a bogus equals method something like simply `return false;` see what happens

Comment: @KevinBowersox Thanks. Will try and then I will post the answer to my own question. :-)

Comment: Got it cleared. It doesn't look into equals method. It compare ever field of both the objects using reflection and then decide whether to fire Update query or not.